# Update statement not updating table but inserting new entry into table instead

Tags: php, html, mysql

For the life of me I cannot figure out why my update statement will not update the table row but instead it creates a new row.  I have an ID column that is the unique identifier and is auto_increment, I am just not sure if you can update an auto_incremented data set the way i am trying to.

I have a form that is echo'ing data from the database into the fields and then am using it to edit the fields and update them.

The code:

```
<?php
$EntryID = $_GET['Eid'];
$IDlist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM BD WHERE Id='$EntryID'");
$IDresults = mysql_fetch_array($IDlist);

$update_query = "UPDATE `BD` SET `Id` ='$IDresults['Id']',`EntryTitle` = '$MyTitle',`EntryDescription` = '$MyDescription',`Category` = '$MyCategory' WHERE `Id` ='$EntryID'";
mysql_query($update_query);

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
else{
header('location: /admin/bd-edit-entry.php?sub=1');
exit();
  }
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Any help or advice would be a great.

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions as they are [in the deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: is MySQLi much different? Also could you suggest why an update statement is inserting a new line?  Is it to do with the auto_increment?

Comment: An UPDATE statement should __never__ insert a new record... at worst, you'll get 0 records updated. Please provide some evidence of this bug in MySQL that nobody else has encountered before

Comment: And yes, MySQLi is very different if you use prepared statements

Comment: This might not be the issue, but you're updating the `Id` field, as well as using it in the WHERE clause. As far as I can see, it should have the same value both times, but there's no need to include it in the update part.

Comment: SQL injection?? Its within an admin area anyway.  I'm now getting Error: Query was empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET `Id` ='$IDresults['Id']'
```

should be either:

```
SET `Id` ='$IDresults[Id]'
```

or

```
SET `Id` ='{$IDresults['Id']}'
```

If you turn on error reporting, you should get errors about a bad index.

Or you can leave this column out of the update entirely, since this column isn't changing.